# Is there any way to create topics in Open JMS other than admin UI?

Tags: jms, openjms

I am able to create topics in  Open JMS using admin UI. Is there any Java API or REST API or shell command to do so?

Comment: Most providers automatically create the topic as soon as there first producer or consumer is created, though I don't know Open JMS and how it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Administration API](http://openjms.sourceforge.net/usersguide/admin.html) can be used in Java.

Sample code:

```
import org.exolab.jms.administration.AdminConnectionFactory;
import org.exolab.jms.administration.JmsAdminServerIfc;

// ...
    String url = "tcp://localhost:3035/";
    JmsAdminServerIfc admin = AdminConnectionFactory.create(url);

    String topic = "mytopic";
    Boolean isQueue = Boolean.FALSE;
    if (!admin.addDestination(topic, isQueue)) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create topic " + topic);
    }
```